# Webpart Deployment is very slow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I play with Sharepoint 2010 und VS 2010 Webparts.
The deployment of the webpart from VS to sharepoint takes about 25 sec.
But when I start the sharepoint website from ie it takes about 2-3 minutes for the
first time after deployment of the new webpart.

Is this the normal time ?

thanx 
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

What are your system specs? 2010 requires a bit more memory (I'd recommend 6GB but 4GB is usable).

Also, if you are using SQL Server you will want to limit the amount of memory it is consuming as well.